# Are there drivers for OpenGL 4.3 for [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] (Ubuntu 14.04)

Tags: drivers, graphics, c++, opengl, c

I want to be able to do opengl4.3 c/c++ programming, the [AMD/ATI] Seymour [Radeon HD 6400M/7400M Series] should be able to support it, I just don't know what drivers I have to install

Also I have installed the propriety driver (Using Video driver for the AMD graphics accelerators from fglrx)

Answer (score 1):

The open source radeon drivers support up to OpenGL 3.3 currently. To get OpenGL 4.x support, you must install the latest version of Catalyst -- 14.4 has support for up to OpenGL 4.4.

http://www2.ati.com/drivers/linux/amd-catalyst-14-4-rev2-linux-x86-x86-64-may6.zip

Answer (score -1):

You need to install [`xserver-xorg-video-radeon`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=precise&section=all&arch=any&keywords=xserver-xorg-video-radeon&searchon=names) driver.

```
sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-video-radeon
```

Comment: already installed it

Comment: The open-source radeon driver only supports OpenGL up to 3.3.